# threads waiting unexpectedly not sure whats causing

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I'm wanting to stop traffic of opposing direction from crashing om the bridge. if the randomized get all cars heading east it works fine. It hangs on west bound traffic. im have a feeling that there's a better was to stop threads from colliding as im using so many `sem_post()` and `sem_wait()`
any suggestions or help welcome, still just learning threads so i expect to be missing something.

eventually i want randomised traffic from both direction as well as trucks that need the bridge all to them selves where as cars can share so long as the traffic flow is the same.

````
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define MAXCARS 5
#define MAXWAIT 10
#define CROSSINGTIME 2

int G_direction = 0;
int carNum;
int retVal=0, lower = 0, upper = 1;
int car_rid[MAXCARS];
pthread_t threads[MAXCARS];

sem_t direc_sem, car_E, car_W,bridge_sem;

const char* printRandoms() ///randomise the cars direction
{
    int num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
    if (num == 0){
        //left headed west
        return "west";
    }else return "east";
    //return num;
    
}
void *car(void *arg) {
    int carNum = (int)(intptr_t)arg; //what car is it 
    const char* direction = printRandoms(); //random direction
    printf(" car no %d is idling, planning to go %s \n",carNum, direction);// test print
    sleep( rand() % MAXWAIT ); // wait a random amounnt of time 

    sem_wait(&direc_sem); //isolate the direction value
    if(direction == "west"){
        if (G_direction > 0){//g_direction -1 = one car headed west -2 two headed west
            sem_wait(&car_E);//if traffic flow is in the wrong direction wait for the semaphore
        }
        G_direction--;//->> move ON the bridge
        if (G_direction == -1){//if last car on bridge lock east bound traffic
            sem_wait(&car_W);
        }
    }
    sem_post(&direc_sem);

    sem_wait(&direc_sem);//isolate the direction value
    if(direction == "east"){
        if (G_direction < 0){//g_direction 1 = one car headed east 2 two headed east
            sem_wait(&car_W);//if traffic flow is in the wrong direction wait for the semaphore
        }
        G_direction++;//->> move ON the bridge
        if (G_direction == 1){//if last car on bridge lock west bound traffic
            sem_wait(&car_E);
        }
    }
    sem_post(&direc_sem);

   
    printf("car no %d goes ON the bridge heading %s \n", carNum,direction);
    
    sleep(CROSSINGTIME);
   
    printf("car no %d goes OFF the bridge heading %s \n", carNum, direction);

    sem_wait(&direc_sem);//isolate the direction value
    if(direction == "west"){
        
        G_direction++;//->> move OFF the bridge
        if (G_direction == 0){//if last car on bridge unlock other traffic
            sem_post(&car_W);
        }
    }
    sem_post(&direc_sem);

    sem_wait(&direc_sem);//isolate the direction value
    if(direction == "east"){
        
        G_direction--;//->> move off the bridge
        if (G_direction == 0){//if last car on bridge unlock other traffic
            sem_post(&car_E);
        }
    }
    sem_post(&direc_sem);

    

}

int main( void ){
    sem_init(&direc_sem, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&car_E, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&bridge_sem, 0, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXCARS; i++){
       retVal = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL,car ,(void *)(intptr_t)i);
        if(retVal!=0){
           printf("pthread_create failed in %d_th pass\n",i);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);        
       }
    }
     for (int i = 0; i < MAXCARS; i++){
        retVal = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        if(retVal!=0){
               printf("pthread_join failed in %d_th pass\n",i);
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);        
        }
    }
   
    //sem_destroy(&carLock);
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `if(direction == "west")` This is not guaranteed to work. Either ditch the strings and use e.g. an `enum` instead, or use `strcmp` to compare the strings.

Comment: ok thats an easy thing i can try to fix ill give  it a try

Comment: To add to @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.'s point, C-Style strings behave a lot like strings in Java, in that the `==` operator compares *pointers* instead of the contents of each string. You should use `strcmp(str1, str2) == 0` instead.

Comment: thanks it good contex to have i've change the way i test the cars direction and the error perssists. i change the direction to only read east bount traffic and the code runs as expected```const char* direction = "east";//printRandoms(); //random direction``` im just not sure on the interaction between the opposing flows of traffic threads.

Comment: I commented on your later question that you probably need to add `sem_init(&car_W, 0, 1);`. Since you ask about alternatives to semaphores, you could use pthread mutexes.

Comment: running the posted code through a C compiler results in several messages like: `untitled.c:41:18: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]` so the posted code needs several modifications before it is ready to try and execute.  Suggest, for `gcc`, using the options:  `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`.  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: to compare strings, such as for: `if(direction == "west"){`  suggest using `if( strcmp( direction, "west") == 0){

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `printf("pthread_create failed in %d_th pass\n",i);` Error messages should be output to `stderr` rather than `stdout`  Suggest using `fprintf( stderr, "error message\n" );`